# htaccess redirect www to non-www and http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I found different solutions for `www to non-www`, `http to https`, or a combination of these two. However, not all of them work as expected. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792611/redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www-url), it cannot fulfil my third condition below.

**Conditions**

```
 1. domain.com/* -> https://domain.com/*
 2. www.domain.com/* -> https://domain.com/*
 3. https://www.domain.com/* -> https://domain.com/*
```

I combined two of the solutions I found and got the below. It works, but I am not sure if it's correctly written and used. I totally have no knowledge about using .htaccess rules. So I am hoping someone can give a hand. Thank you!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: 1st rule should have: `RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]`

Comment: @anubhava hi, when you said "should have" does it mean replace the second line?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

I think redirecting `www to non-www` is better done with a simple DNS `CNAME` record:

```
NAME:   www.domain.com.
TYPE:   CNAME
RECORD: domain.com
```

That would leave you with only the `http to https` redirect in Apache, which it looks like you have covered.

Comment: Hi, i already have exactly the same `CNAME` record in my DNS records since the beginning, but it doesn't seem to help before I use the .htaccess code. Any idea?